# close window in button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, click, vb.net-2010

I'm creating message dialogue box using JavaScript alert statement. That dialogue box contains one button. In that button click i want to close the current window.

**JavaScript**

```
<script language="javascript" >
     function Confirmation() {
         var win = window.open('', '_self');
         if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close the form?") == true)
             win.close();
         else
             return false
     }

  </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <td class="style5">
<asp:ImageButton ID="close" runat ="server" ImageUrl ="image/button_blue_close.png" OnClientClick="return Confirmation()"
        Height="16px" Width="21px" ImageAlign="Right"/>
 </td>
```

my code only close the window when i click the image button. But i want to close the window in button click of the dialogue box

```
 my code in vb.net
 -----------------
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "message", "alert('Please Raise the  ticket for particular event');", True)
```

Comment: Can you include the code with the `alert()`? Or did you mean the `confirm()` you have there? Your question is confusing.

Comment: s i edit my code.pls see

Comment: it open  dialogue box with one button .in that button click i want to close the current window

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question properly, you want to close your parent windown from dialog box. Though the code you have written will close your dialog box and not your parent window. To close your parent window, you can use below code:

`window.opener.close();`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like that, if you want to close your parent window

```
`<script language="javascript" >function Confirmation(){if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close the form?") == true) window.opener.close();else return false;}</script>`
```

Comment: the above  code is called when i click the image button is in it

Comment: Above code should call from your dialog-box button click event. Thumb-rule wherever you want to close you parent window from child window. Control should present in the child window.